# Android M Speech volume

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-speech-api

Currently I'm learning how to use the Android Speech library. I tested it with various stream types.

This is my code:

```
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
   params.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, 1);
   speech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params, "Yow");
```

Unfortunately the device seems not to use the Alarm volume. I also noticed that when I use the alarm stream in `MediaPlayer`, it increments the volume gradually.

Before I upgraded to Marshmallow, the volume was instantly loud enough.

How can I increase the volume of the speech engine so it instantly uses the Alarm volume?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: Not yet. But this project is currently on hold.

Comment: I had to use deprecated speak() method to achieve the functionality